# Maximum Int in Idris

Tags: bounded-types, idris2

How do I get `maxBound` of `Int` in Idris? I want to write my code such that it works both when the word size is 32-bit and 64-bit, and I think that will change the size of the Int.

Comment: iirc, `Int32` and `Int64` etc. are now favoured over `Int`

Comment: @joel, I don't want to change the types of the C code I am binding to.

Comment: what C type are you binding `Int` to?

Comment: @joel `int`. That's why I used `Int` in Idris.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a function in Idris. I think I asked this question on the language forum a while back, and the answer was no, but I might be misremembering.

That said, you seem to be assuming that `Int` and `int` have the same width for every platform. I don't know if that's true, but if it were, you could write an FFI function to get `INT_MAX` from `#include <limits.h>`.

Really though, I'd ask if you need to use a C `int` (and Idris `Int`) at all, and whether you can use `int32_t` and `Int32`, or `int64_t` and `Int64`.